# iOS whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

**While i am Moving From PassCode Controller to OTP ViewController, iam getting the following error in console:**

> Warning: Attempt to present < OTPController: 0x1e56e0a0 > on <
>   PassCodeController: 0x1ec3e000> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

**This is the code I'm using to change between views:**

```
UIStoryboard  *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    OTPViewController *lOTPViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OTPViewController"];
    lOTPViewController.comingFromReg = true;

    [self presentViewController:lOTPViewController animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
```

**i am presenting PassCode Controller From RegistrationViewController:**

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        PassCodeViewController *passVC =  [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PassCodeViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:passVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: from where you present **PassCodeController**

Comment: UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
use self.storyboard instead

Comment: AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
appDelegate.window.rootViewcontroller present...

Comment: @PKT this is not a relevent things of storyboard and all plz avoide this

Comment: Thanks for all.                                                                                               This code is working For me:       OTPViewController *lOTPViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OTPViewController"];
        lOTPViewController.comingFromReg = true;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:lOTPViewController animated:YES];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happen because of two viewcontroller present and dismiss at a same time or you are trying to present ViewController immediately at the viewcontroller open `ViewDidload` method so

**First:**

- Present ViewController from `viewDidAppear` Method or instead of `ViewDidload`.

**Second:**

I suggest to make use of completion method for present and dismiss viewcontrolelr like following example:

```
[self presentViewController:lOTPViewController animated:YES
                             completion:^{

        }];
```

**UPDATE:**

Create a separate method of presenting a OTPViewController like following:

```
-(void)PresentOTPViewController
{

    UIStoryboard  *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    OTPViewController *lOTPViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OTPViewController"];
    lOTPViewController.comingFromReg = true;

    [self presentViewController:lOTPViewController animated:YES
                     completion:^{}];

}
```

Now call this method with 1 second Delaya using `performSelector`

```
[self performSelector:@selector(PresentOTPViewController) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0 ];
```

You need to put above performselect code in

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
 [self performSelector:@selector(PresentOTPViewController) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0 ];
}]; // this is the dismiss method of PassCodeViewController
```

t

Comment: Yah thats the issue is otp vc is dismissed and you immediately present new vc so add 1-2 second delay in between dismiss and new vc present

Comment: I am on lunch now will update answer within 15 mint 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111408/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-priya).

Answer (score 2):

Try to present it from rootViewController,

`[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:lOTPViewController animated:YES
                     completion:nil];`

Comment: @Vijay.....check it with updated Question...http://stackoverflow.com/q/37110406/6285383

Comment: instead of `self` keyword for presenting your view controllers try with `self.view.window.rootViewController`. Use this code where you are facing that error!

Answer (score 1):

Use below line of code ..

```
// you need to create UIStoryboard object by giving name of your storyboard
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
// here you need to create storyboard ID of perticular view where you need to navigate your app 
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewContIdentifire"];

// if use presentViewController this will not enables you to go back to previous view
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
                        **// OR**
// using pushViewController lets you to go back to the previous view
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```